# SQL Server - Is there a way to do a row by row comparison (with multiple constraints) to find what doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to return if there isn't a row for a person for one of the subjects if they are all compiled (see below in Table). Theoretically, what I would want is the result of the code is to return

```
Name      State Subject
Doe, John TX    History
```

Should I be adding a new column to my Table 2 or another table all together that can cross walk to help me get these results?

Right now I have it to where multiple tables are made by selecting all where Subject = *blah*, but I was hoping to keep the larger table together because have about 10 subjects to go through.

**TBL1**

```
Name    State   Subject Grade
Doe, John   TX  Math    0.45
Doe, John   TX  Science 0.85
Doe, Jane   MS  Math    0.45
Doe, Jane   MS  Science 0.85
Doe, Jane   MS  History 0.75
```

**TBL2**

```
Doe, John   TX
Doe, Jane   MS
```

Thanks

Comment: You need normalization. http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: That's a very badly designed table.

Comment: @Eric that's not very helpful criticism... what is wrong with it? I mean this table is a very simple, very truncated version of the table that I'm using that has a lot less rows and a lot less columns. The point was just to say that I have a table with the students and their states that I want to match on to the first table and figure out what subjects are missing

Comment: @SkywalkerPadawan It is good to start with a properly designed table, no matter how simple is your data.  A supposedly simple query might be impossible to get because of a badly designed tables.

Comment: @Eric yeah... but you still haven't told me how to "properly design" my table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a `cross join` to get all the combinations and then filtering out the ones that exist.  For instance:

```
select ns.*, s.*
from (select distinct name, state from t) ns cross join
     (select distinct subject from t) s
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.name = ns.name and t.state = ns.state and t.subject = s.subject
                 );
```

Comment: Can you please also suggest how to normalize this table structure ?

Comment: @PrabhatG: you need to ask a new question

Comment: I think this would work, but I'm confused about the ns, s, and t variables when I only have two tables?

Comment: @SkywalkerPadawan They're not variables.  They're table aliases.  You can replace the t with your actual table name.

Comment: @Eric I understand that, but there are only two tables... so if there is ns and s, where would t come from?

Comment: @SkywalkerPadawan Since you don't give table name, t is for your table name, whatever it is (TBL1 I guess).